# Google Analytics site search

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to enable the internal site seach tracking with Google Analytics.

So at analytics page, account `mysite.com`: Profile Settings => Site Search Settings, do track enabled.

At my site when someone make a search for test, URL looks like: `mysite.com/search?keyword=test`. At the query parameter I added `search?keyword=` but I haven't seen any results so far, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the search result page is at `mysite.com/search?keyword=test`, then the query parameter is `keyword`

Comment: Thanks you! After i made the changes, it was a matter of time since i started search tracking :)

Answer (score 0):

**Tracking Custom Search Engine results in Google Analytics**

> 1. Access your Custom Search Engine by either signing in to your Google Account used for creating the CSE or by visiting
>      http://www.google.com/coop/manage/cse/. Then select Control Panel for
>      the Search Engine you wish to track.
> 2. Click Look and feel.
> 3. Select a layout and style.
> 4. Click Save & Get Code.
> 5. Select the check box for Include Google Analytics Site Search tracking code.
> 6. Under Specify your Google Analytics Site Search account id, enter your Google Analytics ID.
> 7. Under Specify your Google Analytics Site Search query parameter name, enter the query parameter you want to use.
> 8. Include the Google Analytics Tracking Code on the page where you'd like the Custom Search element to appear. Read How do I add tracking
>      code to my website? for more details.

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98222